# Compare string element to ASCII value

Tags: c, string, char

I am writing a C program for my exam and I am facing some issues.
For example, in an this exercise :

```
char y = 'a';

if (y >= 65)
    printf("MAJOR");
```

or :

```
char a[] = "bare";

if (a[0] >= 65)
    printf("MAJOR");
```

I would really like to get `MAJOR` printed but I always get an error.

My aim is to see if an element of my `char` array  is major or equals to a specified ASCII value (`65` is `'A'`).

Also I got a pointer that actually needs to move in the `char` array: how can I scroll it trough until `'\0'` ?

I tried with :

```
for (i = 0 ; &p->info[i] != '\0' && &s[i] != '\0'; i++)
                     // the info field of this struct is type char *
```

Where `info` is `char*` and `s` is `char s[]`.

Is this for loop fine?

EDIT: NEW ISSUE

It's really weird I got a generic error trying to run just this line of code:

```
char y = 'a';
```

Seems that my 'y' variable is filled with an underscore instead of 'a'....?
I'm using Xcode right now

Comment: "*but i always get an error :(*" -- What's the error?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You haven't explained the error too. Post a small version of the program which reproduces the error. Also, post the **exact** error message along with relevant details.

Comment: Solved :) little Xcode issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, if you're checking for null-termination, you need to change

```
  &p->info[i] != '\0' && &s[i] != '\0'
```

to

```
 (p->info[i] != '\0') && (s[i] != '\0')
```

because, `\0` is a *value*, not an *address*.

---

EDIT:

I am still not very sure, but maybe you want to achieve something like below. It seraches the whole *array* for CAPS letter and prints "MAJOR" if it finds one.

Pseudo-code:

```
char arr[] = "bAre";
int len = strlen(arr);
for (int counter = 0; counter < len; counter++)
{
       if ( (arr[counter] >= 'A') && (arr[counter] <= 'Z'))  //need ending condition also
            printf("MAJOR\n");
}
```

**Point-to-note here:** If you don't limit the check at `'Z'`, a value of `'a'` also  satisfies `>= 65`.

Comment: Still not working, what can you say about the second piece of code? (char a[] = bare) What can i do to get that right?

Comment: Gonna try to put that in my code, and gonna mark as right if it solves this evening! thank you either

Answer (score 1):

First, lowercase letters greater than capital letters，'a'(97) is bigger than 'A'(65), so it seems that in your code, 'a' is also a 'MAJOR'.

So if you want to get a 'MAJOR', you should use

```
char y = 'a';

if (y >= 'A' && y <= 'Z')
{
    printf("MAJOR");
}
```

Next, info is char* and s is char s[], so you need change

```
&p->info[i] != '\0' && &s[i] != '\0'
```

to

```
(p->info[i] != '\0') && (s[i] != '\0')
```

because,

\0 is a value, not an address...

infor[i] and s[i] are all char...

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this also-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{


char arr[] = "bAre";
int i;
        for (i = 0; arr[i] != '\0' ; i++)
        {
            if ( (arr[i] >= 65) && (arr[i] <= 90)) {  //need ending condition also
                    printf("%c-",arr[i]);
                    printf("MAJOR\n");
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```